# Is this enough to determine maximum and minimum of a function?

Tags: functions, continuity

I have to find the maximum and minimum of a function:

$$f(x) = e^{\frac{x+1}{2}}, x\in [-1,1]$$

Is it enough if I just say:

Since the function is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and is increasing,

the maximum will be for $f(1) = e$

and the minumum $f(-1) = 1$.

Comment: Once you prove monotonicity you don't even need the continuity premise to make that argument.

Comment: You don't need the continuity hypothesis: if you have a function which is non-decreasing in an interval $[a,b]$ then it's maximum is attained in $b$, and its minimum in $a$.

Comment: @dxiv Do I need to prove it here?

Comment: You wrote "*the function ... is increasing*". That statement is correct, but you have to back it up somehow.

Comment: To show it is increasing just notice that if $h>0$ then $e^{h/2}>1$ and therefore $f(x+h)=e^{h/2}f(x)>f(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $f$ is increasing.

$$f(1) > f(x) > f(-1), \forall x \in (-1,1)$$

Comment: Is this the proof that $f(x)$ is increasing?

Comment: nope, you can take its derivative to show that it is strictly increasing.

Comment: So I can say:

$${f}'(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x+1}{2}}$$

and if we check the sign on the monotone interval $(-1,0)$ (we can take 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{0+1}{2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{+1}{2}}$$
$$\approx 0.824$$

And since $f(x)$ is positive (increasing) on the (only) monotone interval , we can say that it's increasing and state the minimum and maximum.

?

Comment: I don't quite get the monotone interval part. exponential function is positive, hence the derivative is positive and the function $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I meant that, 

$$\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x+1}{2}}$$

is positive on $-1<x<1$

Comment: Or (this makes more sense) since

$$e^{\frac{x+1}{2}}$$

is aways positive, then the whole expression (the derivative) is positive, so the function is increasing. Is this better?

Comment: yup, your latest two posts are mentioning the same thing right? yup, exponential  functionis positive, hence the derivative is positive, and the function is increasing.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!